# Can't access remote mysql ubuntu ERROR 2003 (HY000):

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, tcp

I am trying to connect to remote mysql 
mysql -u user -p -h remotehost

and get the error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server 'remotehost' (110)
```

bind-address was set to 0.0.0.0

I ran netstat -tuplen and got:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
114        3673093     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
113        13137       -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
0          2018912     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
0          16772       -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      
0          3663980     -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      
0          2018914     -
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      
0          16773       -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*                           
113        13138       -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           
0          2002        -
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was just a security issue which was not allowing connection from that ip.